# can database and media folder be moved to a different drive?

Tags: mysql, media-library

I have to move my site from Drive `C:\` to Drive `E:\`.

Is there a better way to do this than uninstalling the following:

- Wordpress
- PHP
- MySQL
- Apache

and re-installing on Drive `E:\`?

For example, how can I move just the database files and media folder to Drive `E:\`?

Answer (score 1):

DISCLAIMER : Only a MySQL DBA, not WordPress expert

You could migrate the database as follows:

Very first thing is to locate the `my.ini` for MySQL. Search all data volumes until you locate `my.ini`

Next, login to MySQL and run

```
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'datadir';
```

This will tell you what folder MySQL data is stored. For this example, let's say it returned `C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL 5.0\data`

You can shutdown mysql from the DOS Command Line as follows

```
net stop mysql
```

Next, Make your own folder on Drive `E:`

```
mkdir E:\MySQLDB
```

You can then copy the MySQL Data Folder to Drive `E:`

```
cd "C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL 5.0\data"
xcopy /s * E:\MySQLDB
```

Here is the good part: Run notepad on `my.ini` and replace datadir in it with

```
[mysqld]
datadir=E:/MySQLDB
```

Finally, startup mysql

```
net start mysql
```

Check the Task Manager. If you see mysqld.exe in the processlist, CONGRATULATIONS !!!

In terms of the other LAMP components, you will have to examine `php.ini` and other related config files and do the same thing.

Comment: Thanks, it was mainly MySQL I was worried about, I have a test installation I can later so I will try it out there. Many thanks again.